# SAP HANA Dynamic Analytic Privilege Procedure with CLOB output parameter not working

Tags: hana, sap-bw

I created a very simple procedure for testing dynamic analytic privilege. I'm getting an error when I define the output parameter as CLOB. However, when I define it as VARCHAR(5000) it works great. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

When I call the procedure from SQL console with output parameter defined as CLOB I have no errors. The error message pops up when I execute the calculation view which has dynamic Analytic Privilege defined with the procedure shared below:

> SAP DBTech JDBC: [258]: insufficient privilege: Could not obtain all relevant analytical privileges for user TEST_USER accessing view ._SYS_BIC.system-local.bw.bw2hana/Zxx_xx due to exception: Invalid SQL AP definition*

According to SAP HANA documentation using CLOB for the output, the parameter is allowed in SPS 03.

https://help.sap.com/viewer/57a523b496cc4531a3676f5d94644899/2.0.03/en-US/63efa79c963d4243ad2a894e2b5bd10c.html

I am on BW and HANA version 2 SPS 3.  HANA DB Version:  2.00.037.03.1566979009

My code:

```
PROCEDURE "_SYS_BIC"."ZTEST::ZTEST_PROC01" (OUT FILTER CLOB)

LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
DEFAULT SCHEMA "_SYS_BIC"
READS SQL DATA AS

BEGIN
    FILTER := '"0COMP_CODE" = ''0001'''; 
END;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize I was testing this on HANA version 1. This works in version 2 SPS3. Sorry for the confusion.